# Поміняти місцями А з/та Б

Tags: різниця-між-словами, сполучники

Як правильніше і чи є взагалі різниця між

> 1. Поміняти місцями А з Б
> 2. Поміняти місцями А та Б

Тобто використовувати *з* чи *та*?

Comment: Мені здається, тут можна обидва варіанти. Як «чим відрізняються А та Б» та «чим відрізняється А від Б». Але обґрунтувати ніяк не можу.

Comment: @Sasha, коли ми вже навчимося (а також навчимо наших модераторів) не робити напів-відповідей у коментарях? Два роки, сотні власних відпорвіде, тисячі вдячних читачів, майже 20к репутації, а віз і нині там… Коментарі існують лише з єдиною метою: уточнення/покращення запитання/відповіді, під яким вони написані. **І все.** Усі інші коментарі мають бути видалені.

Comment: @bytebuster, ми ж уже обговорювали це. Ви багато разів висловлювали свою позицію, я багато разів висловлював свою, я сподівався, що ми обидва зрозуміли, що маємо різні погляди на це. Якщо коротко: (1) я не вважаю напіввідповіді в коментарях чимось поганим; (2) я вважаю, що цей мій комментар не заслуговує бути названим навіть *напів*відповіддю.

Comment: @Sasha Думаю, що суть у тому, що не потрібно вказувати здогади, бо це лише здогади.

Answer (score 1):

#### Як правильніше і чи є взагалі різниця між `з` та `та`?

Спробуємо для початку розібрати: що таке **[`з`](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B7)** та що таке **[`та`](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%82%D0%B0)**?

`З` - це прийменник, який використовують для вказування зв'язку з напрямком.

Наприклад, `я йду з тобою`. Де *`з`* вказує на зв'язок. Тобто *`я`* зв'язаний з *`тобою`* в дії *`йду`*, а не навпаки.

`Та` - це сполучник, який у випадку `а та б` виконує роль `і` та створює перелік літер.

---

*Я особисто використовую `та` для створення пари, тобто перелік лише з двох складових. Якщо ж перелік з більшою кількістю складових, то використовую `і`*.

---

Отже, по суті **обидва вирази не вказують точно на те, який результат вимагають**. Обидва вирази не повні. Можна лише гадати:

1. **`а з б`**

   - де основою є `а`, і можна подумати, що потрібно замінити `а` на `б`;
   - де основою є `а`, але потрібно замінити `а` з `б` на щось, що не вказано;
2. **`а та б`**

   - де потрібно заміни `а` та `б` між собою;
   - де потрібно замінити `а` та `б` на щось, що не вказано.

#### Тобто використовувати з чи та?

Не можливо відповісти на це запитання, коли вирази не повні. А здогади приводять до кількох результатів. Потрібно зрозуміліше пояснити бажаний результат.

---

*Подібні речі потрібно вирішувати програмістам (та й не лише програмістам) щодня під час ознайомлення з текстами завдань.*

Comment: Мені здається ви зовсім відхилились від запитання, я зовсім не бачу аналізу фрази *поміняти місцями ...* Тобто, *я йду з тобою* і *замінити на* - це інше. Можна і ці фрази теж розглянути, але питання саме про *поміняти місцями ...*

Comment: Тим не менше +1, бо ви дали додатковий напрям до роздумів, а саме, тепер мені здається, що варіант *з* кращий, бо однозначніший. Наприклад, другий варіант можна продовжити *поміняти місцями А та Б з В.*